# Testing async.retry with Jest

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a function Im trying to retry with async.retry.

```
export const publish = async (message: string): Promise<void> => {
 sendMessage({ MessageBody: message }, (err, _) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Error: ${err})
      throw Error(`Error`)
    } else {
      console.log(`Published: ${message})
    }
  })
}
```

```
async.retry(
3, 
async () => await publish("message"), 
(err, result) => { if (err){ Console.log("Error") } } 
)
```

I want to mock and test that this function will actually retry and return error/void using async.retry. I have this set up:

```
  test('retry publish. Returns Error',async () => {
    const publishEventsSpy = jest
    .fn()
    .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Error'))
    .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Error'))

    jest.doMock('../emitEvent', () => {
      return {
        publish: publishSpy,
      }
    })

    async.retry(2,
      publishSpy,
      function(err,result){
        if(err){
          console.log(`Error - ${err}`)
        }
      })

    expect(publishEventsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
})
```

I receive this error:

```
    Expected number of calls: 2
    Received number of calls: 1
```

I thought I was mocking this correctly as if I change the expect to

```
expect(publishEventsSpy()).rejects.toThrowError('Error')
```

it passes. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    test('retry publish. Returns Error',async () => {
      const publishEventsSpy = jest
        .fn()
        .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Error'))
        .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Error'))

      jest.doMock('../emitEvent', () => {
        return {
          publish: publishEventsSpy,
        }
      })
      
      // ...
      
      await expect(publishEventsSpy()).rejects.toEqual(new Error('Async error'));
      await expect(publishEventsSpy()).rejects.toEqual(new Error('Async error'));
      expect(publishEventsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    })
```